# Sentence Splitting in Python and making it an Ordered Dict

Tags: python

I want to split my text and store it to make an ordered dict

```
For example:

1.This is my text.
2.This is 2nd Text.
```

I want to split the numbers and text and store it in a ordered dict like

```
Ordered Dict 

"1":"This is my text"
"2":"This is 2nd text"
```

I tried . split but it didn't work for me. How to do this?

```
d = OrderedDict()
text_data = [ "1.This is my text.","2.This is 2nd text"]
for i, f in enumerate(text_data):
id = f.split('.')
d[id] = text_data[i]
print(i, " :: ", id, " =>\n", d[id], "\n" + "*" * 100 + "\n")
```

Where am I going wrong? To make an OrderedDict

Comment: Please correct your indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend the following:

```
from collections import OrderedDict


d = OrderedDict()
text_data = [ "1.This is my text.", "2.This is 2nd text"]

for sentence in text_data:  # Note 1
    num, text = sentence.rstrip('.').split('.', 1)  # Notes 2 & 3
    d[num] = text
```

Notes:

1. You do need to use the `i` from the `enumerate`, so remove it.
2. `rstrip` before you `split`. As you can see there is a dot (`'.'`) at the end of each sentence that might interfere with the `split`. If you however want to keep the last dot (if it exists), simply remove the `.rstrip('.')` part.
3. Pass a second argument to `split` telling it how many *cuts* it should do. Think of the case `'3. A sentence. With a dot in between.'`.

The above produces:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    print('{!r}: {!r}'.format(k, v))

# '1': 'This is my text'
# '2': 'This is 2nd text'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are very close. After splitting string by dot access the elements using index.

**Ex:**

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict()
text_data = [ "1.This is my text.","2.This is 2nd text"]
for i, f in enumerate(text_data):
    val = f.split('.')           #str.split
    d[val[0]] = val[1]           #Use Index. 

for k, v in d.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
news='.'.join(s.split('. ')).split('.')
d=OrderedDict(list(dict(news[i:i+2] for i in range(len(news)-2)).items())[::2])
for k,v in d.items():
    print('"%s": "%s"'%(k,v))
```

Output:

```
"1": "This is my text"
"2": "This is 2nd Text"
```